# Why does minikube doesn't have access to k8s registry?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Running the `minikube start` command, I am getting this message:
This container is having trouble accessing https://registry.k8s.io

and after this the Booting up control plane process takes a long time then gives the following error:

Error starting cluster: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.26.1:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,NumCPU,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1

I have the right `minikube`, `kubectl` , `docker` ... versions.
`$ echo $(minikube docker-env)` this command outputs the following error:

Exiting due to GUEST_STATUS: state: unknown state "minikube": docker container inspect minikube --format=: exit status 1

stderr:

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/minikube/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

But what i don't understand, if I run the `docker run hello-world` , it works (I have the super user permission)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the below commands:

Remove unused data:

```
docker system prune
```

Clear minikube's local state:

```
minikube delete
```

Start the cluster:

```
minikube start --driver=<driver_name>
```

(In your case driver name is docker as per minikube profile list info shared by you)

Check the cluster status:

```
minikube status
```

Also refer to this [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11530) link.

Comment: Worked for me well